# 置換対象文字列をメソッドで渡す方法

Tags: c#

`new Regex`()内をstring型にしてメソッドにして投げるとエラーが返されました。

通常

```
string source ="<!DOCTYPE html><html lang~~~";

Regex reg = new Regex("http://panda.com/(\\d\\d\d\d\\d|\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d)",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

Match match = reg.Match(source);

if (match.Success)
    textBox8.Text = match.Groups[0].Value.Trim();
```

失敗例

```
private void Tikan(string source, string tikan){
    Regex reg = new Regex(tikan,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    Match match = reg.Match(source);

    if (match.Success)
    textBox8.Text = match.Groups[0].Value.Trim();
}
```

また、できれば\d\d\dなどではなく、桁制限の無い連続する半角数字としたいです。

Comment: 上記のコードでは`tikan`の値が分かりませんので、`Console.WriteLine(tikan);`などで確認してみてください。`http://panda.com/(\d\d\d\d|\d\d\d\d\d)`と表示されなければおそらく引数が間違っています。

Comment: 実際に試した時の`source`と`tikan`の値、具体的な「エラー」の内容を書いてください

Comment: \d\d\d関連は正しく設定されています、通常はエラー出さずに成功します。
エラーは見つけられませんでした、alignment errorだったと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正規表現で`\d`など特定のパターンの繰り返しとマッチしたい場合は以下の量指定子を付加します。

- 0回以上 … `\d*`
- 1回以上 … `\d+`
- *n*回以上*m*回以下 … `\d{n,m}`
- *n*回以上 … `\d{n,}`
- *m*回以下 … `\d{,m}`

なお上記の`\d`の部分は任意の文字や`[]`、`()`などに変更できます。